# Can I have multiple GMainContext per GMainLoop?

Tags: glib

How will a GMainLoop look when I add two GMainContext. The documentation is not that clear. But Can someone verify that adding GMainContext does not create a thread. It just adds another event loop for another set of Gsources.

Which GMainContext will be prioritized, when there are 2 contexts attached to the GMainLoop. I assume its thread-default context but just want to make sure.

If someone can also throw an example of why someone might need two GMainContext's instead of just adding the Gsource to the first context.

Basically I am just getting started with GMain stuff and I have an GMainLoop with GmainContext all setup. But wanted to add some idle task on another thread, but I got confused if I should create a new thread or just create a new GMainContext.

Answer (score 2):

> How will a GMainLoop look when I add two GMainContext.

You can only have one `GMainContext` per `GMainLoop`. A `GMainLoop` is at its core just:

```
while (!main_loop_quit_called)
  g_main_context_iteration (loop->context, TRUE);
```

> But Can someone verify that adding GMainContext does not create a thread. It just adds another event loop for another set of Gsources.

Correct. You have to create threads manually.

> Which GMainContext will be prioritized, when there are 2 contexts attached to the GMainLoop. I assume its thread-default context but just want to make sure.

You can’t have two `GMainContext`s attached to one `GMainLoop`, because you can’t iterate one `GMainContext` while blocking on another. Each `GMainContext` boils down to a `poll()` call, and you can’t have two of those running in the same thread concurrently.

The concept of a ‘thread-default context’ just exists so that operations don’t all have to take a `GMainContext *` as an argument.

> If someone can also throw an example of why someone might need two GMainContext's instead of just adding the Gsource to the first context.

This question is very vague and open-ended. Please explain what it is you’re trying to achieve.

> Basically I am just getting started with GMain stuff and I have an GMainLoop with GmainContext all setup. But wanted to add some idle task on another thread, but I got confused if I should create a new thread or just create a new GMainContext.

If you really need a second thread (typically, [you don’t](https://developer.gnome.org/programming-guidelines/stable/threading.html.en)), it should have exactly one `GMainContext`.

See [the guidelines on main contexts](https://developer.gnome.org/programming-guidelines/stable/main-contexts.html.en).

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. As you mentioned, I cannot have multiple GMainContext in a single thread. That explains everything I needed to know.

Comment: New links for main contexts: https://developer.gnome.org/documentation/tutorials/main-contexts.html threading: https://developer.gnome.org/documentation/tutorials/threading.html